# How to Google Mock a method called from a struct

Tags: c++, mocking, googlemock

Let's have this example:

```
    Class A{
         public:
           int Get();
   }
```

In another file:

```
A a;
struct B{
    int res = a.Get(); 
}
```

I would need to Google Mock Get method, however, I will also need to call the real one. I have tried with #ifdef, and it seems to work. Then I decided to mock it in the #ifdef section but it does nothing.

```
#ifdef UNIT_TEST
MOCK_METHOD0(A,Get);
#else
int A::Get(){....}
#endif
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there any cleaner way to do it? Please, any help would be much appreciate it.

Comment: The code you have posted is not C++.

Comment: Almost exact  dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921238/how-to-google-mock-a-method-called-from-a-struct posted by same user.

Comment: @unapersson Off course it is c++

Comment: @Vjo Hmm, so in C++ class is spelt "Class", class and struct definitions don't need to be terminated with a semicolon,  and you can initialise structure members in the structure definition without using a constructor?

Comment: doh right. I missed that, but the rest looks like c++

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Header file:

```
class A{
     public:
       int Get();
};
A a;
```

Source file:

```
int A::Get(){
   ....
}

struct B{
    return res = a.Get();
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You did it wrongly. This is how it should be done :

1) Header file :

```
    struct A
    {
   #ifdef UNIT_TEST
       MOCK_METHOD0(Get, int());
   #else
       int Get();
   #endif
    };
```

2) Source file :

```
#ifndef UNIT_TEST
int A::Get()
{
  // ...
}
#endif
```

Comment: Of course it is C++, I just made it simple. @VJo int Get(){} is already defined outside of the struct as it used many other structs (FSM), so I can not redefine it within the struct...

Comment: Sorry about the misspelled words, but the ideas was to show C++ code.

Comment: @Manuel Ok, fixed the example

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Google Mock has changed quite a bit. Now you can try [delegating to a real object](https://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/CookBook#Delegating_Calls_to_a_Real_Object) described in the cookbook. You can continue setting and checking expectations on your mock, but the calls will also be handled by the real thing.

```
class MockA : public A
{
public:
    MockA()
    {
        ON_CALL(*this, Get()).WillByDefault(Invoke(&real, &A::Get));
    }
    MOCK_METHOD0(Get, int());

private:
    A real;
};
```